# I am getting below full path as output,i don't want full path just output for example "Hello" as output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

PS C:\Users\satis\Desktop\Python.vscode>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\satis\Desktop\Python.vscode'; & 'C:\Users\satis\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\Users\satis.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.11.1422169775\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '59139' '--' 'c:\Users\satis\Desktop\Python.vscode\Novrmber\16thprogram.py'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it will not be shortened because that will lead to cases it does not work, VSC does not know what the current directory of the terminal is

Comment: You can try using external Terminal which has no execution scripts but pure result. Add `"console": "externalTerminal"` in launch.json.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `Code Runner` extension, the output will be like this:

[image]

And you can also change the value of `console` to `internalConsole` in the launch.json, the output be like this:

[image]